# Custom View fills parent while it should only wrap around the content

Tags: android

I created a custom view that allows me to give a stroke around my text.
It works perfectly fine so far, only problem I'm currently having is that it doesn't wrap around the content. It actually seems to fill the entire parent.

I just need it to wrap the text so I can get the rest of my design back to as it was before I created the custom view.

This is my class

```
public class DrawText extends View {

    String text = "blank";
    float textSize = 90;
    Context context;

    public DrawText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.context = context;
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DrawText, 0, 0);

        try{
            text = a.getString(R.styleable.DrawText_titleText);
        }
        finally
        {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void setTextSize(float size) {this.textSize = size;}

    public void setText(String text) {this.text = text;}

    public String getText() {return text;}

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Typeface font = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC);
        TextPaint strokePaint = new TextPaint();
        strokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        strokePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        strokePaint.setTextSize(90);
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        strokePaint.setDither(true);
        strokePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        strokePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        strokePaint.setTypeface(font);

        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setTextSize(90);
        textPaint.setTypeface(font);
        textPaint.setDither(true);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setShadowLayer(1, 4, 4, Color.BLACK);

        StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 1.0f, false);
        StaticLayout mStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(text, strokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 1.0f, false);

        int textHeight = (getHeight()/2) - (mTextLayout.getHeight()/2);
        int textWidth = (getWidth()/2);

        canvas.translate(textWidth, textHeight);

        mStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);
        mTextLayout.draw(canvas);

        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

in my layout it's used as follows.

```
<com.example.sw_stage.fancomglass.Drawables.DrawText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:titleText="@string/streaming_fromcontacts"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
            android:id="@+id/contact_name" />
```

I'm new to using custom views, I think I should be doing something with the onMeasure method but I'm clueless how I should be using this to achieve my goal.

Comment: You need to measure your view, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#layouteevent

Comment: why your DrawText extends to view if you just want text in it , you should extend to textview.

Comment: @Sajal if I make it extend `TextView` it won't show me anything at all anymore. So unless you would happen to know how to fix that I'm staying away from using it.

Comment: I tried something extending TextView and working fine.If I am right, you need only background or border around your textView??